# Sum if matching columns with groupby in dplyr r

Tags: r

I need help to "sumif" with dplyr and group_by, just like that:

Sample df:

```
df = data.frame(year = c(1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1990,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991,1991),
                    month = c(seq(1,12), seq(1,12)),
                    value = c(2,4,5,3,4,6,7,5,4,3,6,4,5,6,5,4,5,6,4,3,5,6,4,6))
    
    df %>%
      group_by(year) %>%
      mutate(summonths12345 = "sum of values of months 1,2,3,4,5")
```

this is my main goal for my df:

```
year month value summonths12345
1990     1     2  18
1990     2     4  18
1990     3     5  18
1990     4     3  18
1990     5     4  18
1990     6     6  18
1990     7     7  18
1990     8     5  18
1990     9     4  18
1990    10     3  18
1990    11     6  18
1990    12     4  18
1991     1     5  25
1991     2     6  25
...     ..    ..  ...
```

Comment: Try `mutate(total = sum(value[month %in% 1:5]))`.

Comment: but i want a new column with these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a filter and re-join. Probably not efficient but works well.

```
summary <- df %>%
    filter(month < 6) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(summonths12345 = sum(value)) %>%
    right_join(df, by="year")
```

Do you need it to be dynamic, as in a YTD type function?

```
library(lubridate)

summary <- df %>%
    filter(month < month(Sys.Date())) %>%
    group_by(year) %>%
    summarize(summonths12345 = sum(value)) %>%
    right_join(df, by="year")
```

Comment: Great, just a question: and if i want to use months 10,11,12,1,2,3 ?

Comment: Change your filter to `filter(month %in% c(10, 11, 12, 1, 2, 3)`